# EAV on postgres using jsonb

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to implement EAV pattern using `Attribute`->`Value` tables but unlike standard way values stored in `jsonb` filed like `{"attrId":[values]}`. It's help make easy search request like:

`SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.attributes @> "{1:[2]} AND p.attributes @> "{1:[4]}"`

Now I'm wondering is it will be a good approach, and what is a effective way to calculate count of available variations, for example:

`-p1- {"width":[1]}
-p2- {"width":[2],"height":[3]}
-p3- {"width":[1]}`

Output will

`width:` 1 (count 2); 2 (count 1)

`height:` 3 (count 1)

when select `width` 2

`width:` 1 (count 0); 2 (count 1)

`height`: 3 (count 1)

Comment: Why are you storing the value in a `[]` list?

Comment: I thought I should keep a few var's. Like multi-value attribute. But not sure, maybe better create additional key for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### *"Flat is better than nested" -- the zen of python*

I think you would be better served to use simple key/value pairs and in the rare event you have a complex value, then make it a list.  But I don't see that use case.

Here is an example which answers your question. It could be modified to use your structure, but let's keep it simple:

First create a table and insert some JSON:

```
# create table foo (a jsonb);
# insert into foo values ('{"a":"1", "b":"2"}');
# insert into foo values ('{"c":"3", "d":"4"}');
# insert into foo values ('{"e":"5", "a":"6"}');
```

Here are the records:

```
# select * from foo;
          a
----------------------
 {"a": "1", "b": "2"}
 {"c": "3", "d": "4"}
 {"a": "6", "e": "5"}
(3 rows)
```

Here is the output of the json_each_text() function from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html

```
# select jsonb_each_text(a) from foo;
 jsonb_each_text
-----------------
 (a,1)
 (b,2)
 (c,3)
 (d,4)
 (a,6)
 (e,5)
(6 rows)
```

Now we need to put it in a table expression to be able to get access to the individual fields:

```
# with t1 as (select jsonb_each_text(a) as rec from foo) 
  select (rec).key, (rec).value from t1;

 key | value
-----+-------
 a   | 1
 b   | 2
 c   | 3
 d   | 4
 a   | 6
 e   | 5
(6 rows)
```

And lastly here is a grouping with the SUM function.  Notice the `a` key which was in the database 2x, has been properly summed.

```
# with t1 as (select jsonb_each_text(a) as rec from foo) 
  select (rec).key, sum((rec).value::int) from t1 group by (rec).key;

 key | sum
-----+-----
 c   |   3
 b   |   2
 a   |   7
 e   |   5
 d   |   4
(5 rows)
```

As a final note, `(rec)` has parentheses around it because otherwise it is incorrectly looked at as a table and will result in this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "rec"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's helps me better understand `jsonb` querying. But I still have question about stored format, asked additional more detail question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49599011/looking-for-a-right-eav-structure-based-on-jsonb

Comment: @Ivanov, I replied over there.