# Looking for a right EAV structure based on jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, entity-attribute-value

I wondering what will be the right approach to build EAV on jsonb.
I have `Attribute` -> `Values` tables as like in standard EAV.

```
CREATE TABLE attribute_values
(
  id           INTEGER,
  attribute_id INTEGER,
  value        VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE attributes
(
  id   INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Values will saved in `attributes` filed of `Entity`

```
 CREATE TABLE entity
    (
      id   INTEGER,
      title TEXT,
      attributes JSONB
    );
```

Tables `Attribute` created to control duplicate attributes  their types and better determine what it's a attribute is. For example to avoid: `{weight: 100}` and `{Weight: 100}` or `{weigh: 100}`. `Values` for work with unique values and contain avaliable list of values like color (green, red, white etc.) Values can be preloaded and using for faseted search.

I see several options:

**1.** Store format like

```
[{"attribute_id":1, "value":5},{"attribute_id":1, value:"text"}]
```

where `value_id` will be `custom value` like text or `id` from `Values` table. But I can't understand how to build indexing on this format, for example if `Attribute 10` will `integer`

**2.** leave only `Attribute` table (for controlling attribute `name`) and store data like:

```
{"price": 105, "weight": 100, "color": "white"}
```

. This approach much better for indexing

```
CREATE INDEX entity_index ON entity (((attributes ->> 'price')::int));
```

but I will have problem with translation of text property and controlling of unique values. Also I can't add additional key like in option `1`: `{"attribute_id":1, "value":5, "values": []}`

What will be the best approach to store extra field with unique control (for unique attributes) and with the opportunity to indexing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Objective: You want to store attribute related to a given entity.

I do not recommend a separate table for attribute values like we might have done in years gone by.  Put a `jsonb` field right on the appropriate table and call it `Attributes`.  Add a `GIN` index to it so you can query the values quickly.  Or use the other techniques described within.

Read this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174421/7762

The biggest question here is if you intend to pre-define attribute values.  If you do, there is an extremely efficient way to store them.  If not, then I recommend a standard JSON object.

### If you can pre-define your attributes names AND values:

*This gives you the most control, speed, and still provides flexibility.*

Create a table `Attribute` which has these fields:

- `AttributeID int4 unsigned not null primary key`
- `ParentAttributeID int4 unsigned null`
- `Name varchar(64) not null`
- `Deleted` bool not null default false
- Add an index on `ParentAttributeID`
- Add a trigger to prevent `AttributeID` from changing
- Add a rule on delete do instead set Deleted=True

Then in any table you want to attribute, add this field:

- `AttributeSet" int[] not null default`
- Add a GIN index on that array field
- Also enable the `intarray` extension from https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html

**What has this accomplished?**

You've create a tree of attributes.  It might look like this:

```
ID   Parent  Name
----------------------------
100  NULL    Color
101  100       Blue
102  100       Red
103  100       Green
110  NULL    Size
111  110       Large
112  110       Medium 
113  110       Small
```

Say you have a table called `Items` and on it you've added `AttributeSet`:

```
      ItemID: 1234
        Name: Tee Shirt
AttributeSet: [100, 103, 110, 112]
```

When translated, this means that it has the `Color=Green` attribute, and the `Size=Medium` attribute.  `103` and `112` were enough to store that, but sometimes it's nice to be able to say "Show me all items that have any Size defined", that's why 110 was included.

You can make this lightning fast and ultra flexible.

```
SELECT
  "ItemID", "Name"
FROM
  "Items"
WHERE "AttributeMap" @> ARRAY[103,112]
```

Will return all items that have `Size=Medium` and `Color=Green`

Or you can use the other operators on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html to come up with some awesome queries.

### When you don't know the attribute values but it's a small set:

*This gives you the most speed, control, and is even more flexible.  You can flag new attributes for review if needed.*

You can use the above technique and just dynamically add values to the `Attribute` table if they don't exist.

### When you don't know the attribute values and the values are diverse

*This gives you the most flexibility, but at the expense of control.*

In this case just add this to any table:

- `AttributeMap jsonb not null default '{}'::jsonb`
- Add a GIN index to that field

Write code to validate the values against your `Attribute` table.  Have an indicator there if it is a single or multi-value...

Store like this in the `AttributeMap` field:

```
{
    "Color": "Green", 
    "Size": "Medium", 
    "Categories": ["Sports", "Leisure"]
}
```

Notice that Categories is a multi-attribute.  In your `Attribute` table you should have a field that is `IsMulti bool not null` which will allow you to know how to query for it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use numbers for pre-defined attributes in JSON?

like `"1": "Green"` where 1 is the id of your attribute in your Attributes table

Comment: @Konrad of course it depends on what exactly. you are doing.  But the advantage of the `Attribute` table is that it allows a single 32 bit integer to represent a key/value pair (`ParentAttributeID`/`AttributeID`).   As stated above, if the values are diverse, it's best to just use `jsonb` as per normal.

Comment: I would like to be able to set values for pre-defined attributes only. Classic approach: I have a table with entity id,attribute id and attribute value. You can't set an attribute that doesn't exist because you'll get a foreign key violation. With `jsonb` you don't get that protection because `jsonb` doesn't define any relations so checks have to be done manually.

Comment: And you will have to query available attributes each time to make sure attributes set really exist and are correct.

Comment: @Konrad - again if you are storing known keys and arbitrary values, then plain jsonb object is a good way to go.  If you are storing a high volume of known attributes and known values, then an attribute table and an `int[]` is a great way to go because of how compact and fast it is.   Try to take your proposed sub-table structure and do and/or/not attribute queries in an efficient way.  Your way is relationally correct, no doubt.  But practicalities of computer speed and SQL sometimes compel alternate designs.

Comment: But how do you verify if the attribute you're trying to set e.g. "Color" exists if you're using jsonb? Do you have any dictionary of available attributes? jsonb doesn't impose any restrictions/constraints. If you have known keys and unknown values.

Comment: @Konrad it is simply how you architect your system.  In one system I work on we use an `int[]` to reference the attributes.  It results in a high performance structure like this: https://imgur.com/a/TuRR2pV .  When the `int[]` is processed, it is a simple `= ANY ($ids)` query on the Attribute table.  Therefore if we have a dangling integer in the array it is simply ignored on processing (because it is not found).  If you are using plain `jsonb` objects, then your code should be well aware of know attribute names and ignore any (or raise error) if there are invalid keys.

Comment: @Konrad What I think you can use is a specification jsonb object / column on Categories table (read 'attributes specific to a category'). At this object you can also specify validation rules, type, available / default values. Then you have to build a UI to manage those specification attributes.

Comment: @lexeme "specification jsonb object " you mean storing some kind of schema?

Comment: @Konrad Correct. Of course you then have to maintain UI, the categories editor, that knows how to add new attributes to the specification e.g: `{ name: 'shirts', spec: [ { name: 'color', type: options, required: true, items: ['black, ...']  } ] }`. On edits, when category is selected, you should build a custom form of inputs that match the specification attributes. This is my take on that. I'm highly interested in that topic (solutions) myself. If you adopt that ↑ it will be cool to know about your progress!